# My AWS Rekognition sample code doesn't run

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm new to AWS API, and am trying to run a sample AWS Rekognition code (Celebrity Recognition) described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/celebrities-video-sqs.html). All configurations and credentials are set and the app is running. But it's just stuck in the loop printing:

```
Waiting for job: c0059a6ee383daf6e6be12c39ee609cfadcbexxxxxxxxxx
....................
....................
....................
```

And never get's out. Not sure if anything is wrong with the code or configurations or whatnot.

What are the problems? Why I don't see any results back? Here is the code also in the link.

```
import java.util.List;

import com.amazonaws.services.rekognition.AmazonRekognition;
import com.amazonaws.services.rekognition.AmazonRekognitionClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.rekognition.model.CelebrityDetail;
import com.amazonaws.services.rekognition.model.CelebrityRecognition;
import com.amazonaws.services.rekognition.model.CelebrityRecognitionSortBy;
import com.amazonaws.services.rekognition.model.GetCelebrityRecognitionRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.rekognition.model.GetCelebrityRecognitionResult;
import com.amazonaws.services.rekognition.model.NotificationChannel;
import com.amazonaws.services.rekognition.model.S3Object;
import com.amazonaws.services.rekognition.model.StartCelebrityRecognitionRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.rekognition.model.StartCelebrityRecognitionResult;
import com.amazonaws.services.rekognition.model.Video;
import com.amazonaws.services.rekognition.model.VideoMetadata;
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQS;
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.Message;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class VideoDetectCelebrity {


    private static String bucket = "test-bucket";
    private static String video = "test.mp4"; 
    private static String queueUrl =  "https://sqs.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/xxxx/aws-queue";
    private static String topicArn="arn:aws:sns:us-east-2:xxxx:aws-test";
    private static String roleArn="arn:aws:iam::xxxxxx:role/aws-test-role";
    private static AmazonSQS sqs = null;
    private static AmazonRekognition rek = null;

    private static NotificationChannel channel= new NotificationChannel()
            .withSNSTopicArn(topicArn)
            .withRoleArn(roleArn);


    private static String startJobId = null;


    public static void main(String[] args)  throws Exception{

        sqs = AmazonSQSClientBuilder.defaultClient();
        rek = AmazonRekognitionClientBuilder.defaultClient();

        //=================================================
        StartCelebrities(bucket, video);
        //=================================================
        System.out.println("Waiting for job: " + startJobId);
        //Poll queue for messages
        List<Message> messages=null;
        int dotLine=0;
        boolean jobFound=false;

        //loop until the job status is published. Ignore other messages in queue.
        do{
            messages = sqs.receiveMessage(queueUrl).getMessages();
            if (dotLine++<20){
                System.out.print(".");
            }else{
                System.out.println();
                dotLine=0;
            }

            if (!messages.isEmpty()) {
                //Loop through messages received.
                for (Message message: messages) {
                    String notification = message.getBody();

                    // Get status and job id from notification.
                    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                    JsonNode jsonMessageTree = mapper.readTree(notification);
                    JsonNode messageBodyText = jsonMessageTree.get("Message");
                    ObjectMapper operationResultMapper = new ObjectMapper();
                    JsonNode jsonResultTree = operationResultMapper.readTree(messageBodyText.textValue());
                    JsonNode operationJobId = jsonResultTree.get("JobId");
                    JsonNode operationStatus = jsonResultTree.get("Status");
                    System.out.println("Job found was " + operationJobId);
                    // Found job. Get the results and display.
                    if(operationJobId.asText().equals(startJobId)){
                        jobFound=true;
                        System.out.println("Job id: " + operationJobId );
                        System.out.println("Status : " + operationStatus.toString());
                        if (operationStatus.asText().equals("SUCCEEDED")){
                            //============================================
                            GetResultsCelebrities();
                            //============================================
                        }
                        else{
                            System.out.println("Video analysis failed");
                        }

                        sqs.deleteMessage(queueUrl,message.getReceiptHandle());
                    }

                    else{
                        System.out.println("Job received was not job " +  startJobId);
                        //Delete unknown message. Consider moving message to dead letter queue
                        sqs.deleteMessage(queueUrl,message.getReceiptHandle());
                    }
                }
            }
        } while (!jobFound);


        System.out.println("Done!");
    }


    //Copyright 2018 Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.
    //PDX-License-Identifier: MIT-0 (For details, see https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-rekognition-developer-guide/blob/master/LICENSE-SAMPLECODE.)

    // Celebrities=====================================================================
    private static void StartCelebrities(String bucket, String video) throws Exception{

        StartCelebrityRecognitionRequest req = new StartCelebrityRecognitionRequest()
                .withVideo(new Video()
                        .withS3Object(new S3Object()
                                .withBucket(bucket)
                                .withName(video)))
                .withNotificationChannel(channel);

        StartCelebrityRecognitionResult startCelebrityRecognitionResult = rek.startCelebrityRecognition(req);
        startJobId=startCelebrityRecognitionResult.getJobId();

    } 

    private static void GetResultsCelebrities() throws Exception{

        int maxResults=10;
        String paginationToken=null;
        GetCelebrityRecognitionResult celebrityRecognitionResult=null;

        do{
            if (celebrityRecognitionResult !=null){
                paginationToken = celebrityRecognitionResult.getNextToken();
            }
            celebrityRecognitionResult = rek.getCelebrityRecognition(new GetCelebrityRecognitionRequest()
                    .withJobId(startJobId)
                    .withNextToken(paginationToken)
                    .withSortBy(CelebrityRecognitionSortBy.TIMESTAMP)
                    .withMaxResults(maxResults));


            System.out.println("File info for page");
            VideoMetadata videoMetaData=celebrityRecognitionResult.getVideoMetadata();

            System.out.println("Format: " + videoMetaData.getFormat());
            System.out.println("Codec: " + videoMetaData.getCodec());
            System.out.println("Duration: " + videoMetaData.getDurationMillis());
            System.out.println("FrameRate: " + videoMetaData.getFrameRate());

            System.out.println("Job");

            System.out.println("Job status: " + celebrityRecognitionResult.getJobStatus());


            //Show celebrities
            List<CelebrityRecognition> celebs= celebrityRecognitionResult.getCelebrities();

            for (CelebrityRecognition celeb: celebs) { 
                long seconds=celeb.getTimestamp()/1000;
                System.out.print("Sec: " + Long.toString(seconds) + " ");
                CelebrityDetail details=celeb.getCelebrity();
                System.out.println("Name: " + details.getName());
                System.out.println("Id: " + details.getId());
                System.out.println(); 
            }
        } while (celebrityRecognitionResult !=null && celebrityRecognitionResult.getNextToken() != null);

    }

}
```

Looking at my SQS dashboard, the `aws-queue` has no available messages when running the code:

[image]

Comment: Two things to try: 1) In the AWS console, can you verify that your queue actually has any messages?  2) You can manually add messages to your queue in the AWS console.  Try adding a message and see if your code is able to pick it up.  These 2 together should help you diagnose the issue.

Comment: No messages in the queue. Updated my question with photo.

Comment: I don't know Rekognition specifically all that well, but in general the AWS console is pretty informative.  Can you check Rekognition via the console to see if you have sent any requests?  What I'm getting at here is that you can use the console to debug precisely which step is breaking down.

Comment: Actually now that I look closer at your code, I don't see how the `StartCelebrityRecognitionRequest` knows anything about the SQS queue that you are polling.  I see you provide the `NotificationChannel` but I see nothing related to the SQS queue.  How will Rekognition know to notify that particular queue when it's done?

Comment: There were some `queue subscription to topics` steps needed on SQS that I did on dashboard. Can I do that also in code?!

Comment: Usually AWS is pretty good about providing ways to configure all of this stuff in code, however, it can be pretty nontrivial.  Where I work we have all of our cloud configurations written down as code (scripts, config files, wtc...), but we have an entirely separate git repo to hold it all, because it's a lot.  For getting started I would recommend configuring things manually in the console, it's just going to be a lot faster to get off the ground.

Comment: yeah i wish it was all in code so it could be more deterministic.

Comment: Hi were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: I don't quite remember, but I think it was resolved. Try digging into the resources and online docs.